# Export CSV records with association data

Tags: ruby, csv

I am creating a CSV export for pdforms in my Rails application. At the moment, I have this method in my `pdform` model.

```
def self.as_csv 
  attributes = %w{user date_start date_finish location event_name description acct_num sub reason impact uuid topic}
  CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
    csv << attributes

    all.each do |user|
      csv << attributes.map { |attr| user.send(attr) }
      binding.pry
    end
  end
end
```

This works as intended, however, as shown in `attributes`, I have a user. I when exporting this CSV I am shown the User object. I would like to show the email of the user in the exported CSV.

I attempted to replace it with `attributes = %w{user.email date_start date_finish location event_name description acct_num sub reason impact uuid topic}` however I just get this error:

> undefined method `user.email' for # Did you
>   mean? user_id

I can do `user_id` however. But this is no help to the person who is glossing over this CSV as they do not know who the user associated with that ID is. How can I get the Users email to display in the CSV row rather than the id or the object itself?

Comment: Every attribute in `attributes` should a method that can be invoked in user, make sure user does respond to all of them.

Comment: Seconding above comment. you can make a method `email` on the pdfform model which just delegates to `user.email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably avoid such kind of code in production in favor of something more explicit and easier to read/debug (like defining `user_email` method on the model in question and referring it in the list of attributes to export, or calling `email` and delegating it to the association or whatever else), but if you prefer this kind of concise solutions this might work:

```rb
def self.as_csv 
  attrs = %w{user.email date_start date_finish location event_name description acct_num sub reason impact uuid topic}

  CSV.generate(write_headers: true, headers: attrs) do |csv|
    method_chains = attrs.map { |a| a.split('.') }

    find_each do |user|
      csv << method_chains.map do |chain| 
        chain.reduce(user) { |obj, method_name| obj = obj.try(method_name.to_sym) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It's almost the same as yours with additional `reduce` that "folds" methods chains and a couple of other minor improvements:

- instead of writing headers explicitly via `csv << attributes` I set the headers via the options to `CSV.generate`
- instead of `all.each` I fetch records in batches via `find_each` - it can make a huge difference in case of really large tables